# MySQL Update function not updating table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to update a table data by running the following:

```
UPDATE Products
SET SellPrice = 60
WHERE 'ProductId' = 'P6';
```

The table is not updating even though it is running successfully.
This is the action output i'm getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXIKP.png)

This is the info about the table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8hHJ.png)

I'm using a mac.
What am I doing wrong?

I tried changing it a bit to this:

```
UPDATE Products
SET SellPrice = 60
WHERE ProductId = 'P6';
```

But got this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBCDO.png)

Comment: On the 1st query You are comparing two string literals, 'ProductId' and 'P6'. the 2nd query clearly said that ProductId is not exists

Comment: Please can you share your table schema ? `SHOW CREATE TABLE Products`

Comment: case sensitivity may matter what is the exact name of the field in the  products table for product ID you may need to wrap it in back ticks ` instead of apostrophe ' for mysql